# Iniciante - Comportamento Inesperado em uma variável

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar um código em Python que calcula o valor restante no meu VR e me alerta caso a média por dia baixe de 25. É uma tentativa de entender melhor while e break.

Criei uma variável para o valor total que eu recebo e uma para o valor atual, que é o valor total menos um input que pergunta quanto eu gastei hoje. Ao rodar o código, parece que o valor está sendo adicionado ao meu valor total, ao invés de subtraido. Alguém sabe onde eu errei?

PS: X = é o número de dias contados em um mês.

```
GASTODIA = int(input("Quanto você gastou hoje almoçando?"))
VRTOTAL = (35 * 30)
VRATUAL = (35 * 30) - (GASTODIA)
x = 1
MEDIARESTANTE = VRATUAL/(30 - x)

while MEDIARESTANTE > 25:
    GASTODIA = int(input("Quanto você gastou hoje almoçando?"))
    x = x + 1
    MEDIARESTANTE = VRATUAL / (30 - x)
    print("Você ainda tem " + str(MEDIARESTANTE) + " por dia para gastar.")
    if MEDIARESTANTE < 25:
        print("Pisa no freio, amigão, você só tem 25 reais por dia agora")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, você está calculando MEDIARESTANTE utilizando o valor fixo de VRATUAL e o valor variável de x. Ou seja, você está dividindo o mesmo valor inicial para cada vez menos dias.

```
VRTOTAL = (35 * 30)
VRATUAL = (35 * 30)
x=1
MEDIARESTANTE = VRATUAL/(30 - x)

while MEDIARESTANTE > 25:
    GASTODIA = int(input("Quanto você gastou hoje almoçando?\n")) #Acrescentei um \n para imprimir o valor gasto em nova linha
    VRATUAL = VRATUAL - GASTODIA #Atualizando valor remanescente
    MEDIARESTANTE = VRATUAL / (30 - x)
    x = x + 1   #Prepara para o próximo dia
    if MEDIARESTANTE <= 25:
        print("Pisa no freio, amigão, você só tem {} reais por dia agora".format(MEDIARESTANTE))
        break
    else: #Dessa forma o programa não dirá que você ainda tem tanto antes de mandar você pisar no freio
        print("Você ainda tem {} por dia para gastar.".format(MEDIARESTANTE))
```

Removi a parte que você inseria o gasto do primeiro dia fora do loop. Não é uma boa prática fazer a mesma ação dentro e fora do loop. A mensagem sobre quanto ainda resta não deveria ser mostrada quando você ultrapassou o limite de 25 reais.

Ao entrar no loop você insere o valor gasto no primeiro dia (x=1) e cálcula o valor médio restante (VRATUAL/(30-x)) para os próximos 29 dias. Em seguida, o valor de x é incrementado para que na próxima iteração do loop seja o segundo dia e a média seja feita em cima de 28 dias restantes.

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou muito!

Comment: De nada, Eduardo. Se a minha resposta solucionou o problema, por favor aceita ele clicando no _check_ abaixo da nota dela.

Answer (score -1):

Copiando o seu código no ideone, realmente verifiquei que o comportamento do código é como você diz.

O problema é que cada vez você está aumentando x (`x = x + 1`) e então você subtrai esse valor de 30 `30 - x`. Como o divisor de valor atual está diminuindo, ele aumenta a média restante.

Alterando no *while* a linha `x = x + 1` para `x = x - 1`, ou `30 - x` para `30 + x` os valores da média caem como é desejado

Código no [ideone](https://ideone.com/NKD7EM).

```
GASTODIA = int(input("Quanto você gastou hoje almoçando?"))
VRTOTAL = (35 * 30)
VRATUAL = (35 * 30) - (GASTODIA)
x = 1
MEDIARESTANTE = VRATUAL/(30 - x)

while MEDIARESTANTE > 25:
    GASTODIA = int(input("Quanto você gastou hoje almoçando?"))
    x = x + 1
    MEDIARESTANTE = VRATUAL / (30 - x) ** -1 / 1000
    print("Você ainda tem " + str(MEDIARESTANTE) + " por dia para gastar.")
    if MEDIARESTANTE < 25:
        print("Pisa no freio, amigão, você só tem 25 reais por dia agora")
        break
```

**EDIT**

Alterei a expressão de calculo da média restante. Elevando o resultado a `-1` e divindo por 1000.

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela resposta.

O problema é que essa parte me parece correta. O divisor está diminuindo porque são menos dias restantes no mês para dividir o VR, então teoricamente esta certo.

Fiz a alteração e, apesar da media estar caindo, o comportamento ainda não é o desejado :(

Comment: @EduardoMergener fiz umas alterações no código